# Use of typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

```
typedef struct pjmedia_endpt pjmedia_endpt;
```

declaration of struct pjmedia_endpt endpt and pjmedia_endpt endpt are no ok("Variable has incomplete type struct pjmedia_endpt endpt").

i want to declare a variable of pjmedia_endpt, how to do.

Comment: please clarify your purpose

Comment: i want to declare a variable of pjmedia_endpt.

Answer (score 2):

Until unless you complete the incomplete type like this,

```
struct pjmedia_endpt
{
   member1;
   member2;
   ...
};
```

you can not use `pjmedia_endpt`.

Once you complete the structure, then you can use

```
pjmedia_endpt temp; // Declare a variable to it
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `typedef` establishes a forward declaration. After this forward declaration you can define variables of type "pointer to `pjmedia_endpt`", like this:

```
pjmedia_endpt *ptrVar;
```

However, forward declaration by itself is not enough to declare variables or `struct` fields until the actual definition is provided. You need to define the actual structure of `pjmedia_endpt` before you could start using your newly defied type `pjmedia_endpt` for variable declarations:

```
struct pjmedia_endpt {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `typedef` to define a new type based on a predefined structure or a type. Otherwise you cannot declare a variable with that new type unless you define the pjmedia_endpt structure.

First define your structure:

```
struct pjmedia_endpt{
    // ...
};
```

Then you can assigne a type name to your structure:

```
typedef struct pjmedia_endpt pjmedia_endpt;
```

Then you can declare a variable with the new type:

```
pjmedia_endpt someVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a function need pjmedia_endpt.
    pjmedia_transport_udp_create(pjmedia_endpt* endpt,...);

actually i what i need is a pointer,so instead

```
//declare a pointer.
pjmedia_endpt* endpt;
//do init endpt.then pass pointer to the function.
pjmedia_transport_udp_create(endpt,...);
```

Comment: This should really be an edit of the question, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct pjmedia_endpt{
    // ...
};

// Now Rename the structure

pjmedia_endpt newname;

// And now you can access the member of structure with newname.
```